# Python subprocess don't change my ip adress

Tags: python, ip, subprocess

I write a Python script that should change my IP Adress when it is executed. I looked down the stackoverflow site and saw a few solutions that are similar to mine. By for some reasson my don't do anything. Any clue why?

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['runas', '/user:Administrator', 'netsh interface ip set address name=”Ethernet” static IP-I-Want Subnet Standardgatewey'])
```

When I execute the netsh it works fine but not in the Python script. I use Python 3.5

In the cmd it works fine; here is what I do:

1. Open cmd with Administrator rights
2. Write the comand: `netsh`
3. Now I write the comand `interface ip set address name=”Ethernet” static New-Ip New-Subnet New-Standardgatewey`

The IP is changed, but in the script it does nothing.

I use Windows 10.

Comment: Each argument to the function should be a separate element in the list.  As it is, all of the arguments to `runas` except `/user:Administrator` are joined in one.  That is the same as doing `runas /user:Administrator "netsh interface ip set address ..."` (notice the quotation marks) from the command-line.

Comment: I guessed that this could be the Problem, so I sepereted it to 'runas', '/user:Administrator', 'netsh', 'interface ip set...' but then he gives me out the syntax for that and there are only 3 Elemnts in the list allowed as I see.

Comment: It also gives me some examples: > runas /noprofile /user:mymachine\administrator cmd
> runas /profile /env /user:mydomain\admin "mmc %windir%\system32\dsa.msc"
> runas /env /user:Benutzer@Domäne.Microsoft.com "notepad \"Meine Datei.txt\""

Comment: Can you give the exact code you use in the command line?

Comment: 1)I enter the cmd with Admin Privilage 2) I write the netsh comand and hit <Return> 3) Now I am in the natch so i write interface ip set address name=”Ethernet” static IP-I-Want Subnet Standardgatewey and hit <Return>. It works fine and he change the IP adress to the IP-I-Want and also the Subnet and Standardgetaway

Comment: I edited now the question

Comment: What about `from StringIO import StringIO; subprocess.run(['netsh'], stdin=StringIO('netsh interface ip set address name="Ethernet" static New-Ip New-Subnet New-Standardgateway'))` and run the Python script with administrative privileges?

Comment: I got this error ImportError: No module named 'StringIO'

Comment: User `from io import StringIO` instead of `from StringIO import StringIO`

Comment: If `runas /user:Administrator netsh interface ip set address name=”Ethernet” static IP-I-Want Subnet Standardgatewey` works in the `cmd`, will do so from Python. Use @username to address people.

Comment: Yes.  Sorry, I got the plague of reading for my first Python book one that is targeted to Python 2.  In Python 3, it should be `from io import StringIO`.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Can someone post another full code that could work, I now have a missmatch with lots of errors :(